# Spring application refuses to connect to my MySql database with specified username

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, jdbc, spring-data-jpa

I got some strange situation. When i start my spring boot app with application file:

```
spring:
  jpa:
    show-sql: true
    databasePlatform: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: update
      connection:
        charSet: UTF-8
        characterEncoding: UTF-8
        useUnicode: true
  datasource:
    driverClassName: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
    url: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/deutschlerner_db?serverTimezone=UTC
    username: root
    password: root
```

I recieve the error:

```
java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'mihailzubarev'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

"mihailzubarev" - is just my linux profile name, mysql doesn't have that username but does have "root" user.
This error i can reproduce just typing in terminal `mysql -p` it accepts default linux profile username and expectedly drops the same error. But I specified user name in my application file!!!
Futhermore it is possible to connet the database by defining a Bean in SpringBottApplication file and everything works fine

```
    @Bean
    public DataSource getDataSource() {
        DataSourceBuilder dataSourceBuilder = DataSourceBuilder.create();
        dataSourceBuilder.url("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/deutschlerner_db?serverTimezone=UTC");
        dataSourceBuilder.username("root");
        dataSourceBuilder.password("root");
        return dataSourceBuilder.build();
    }
```

Comment: `spring.main.allow-bean-definition-autowiring= true` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got environtment variable which overrided username value

Comment: Was that causing the problem? Or solving it?

Comment: I solved this. There was 2 env variables defined in /etc/profle SPRING_DATASOURCE_USERNAME and SPRING_DATASOURCE_PASSWORD. They were defined for postgres database for one of projects. It appeared that Spring took  they values for mysql connnection in another project even without ${SOME_VAR} notation.